# Windows Kernel Driver: Does the "HANDLE UniqueThread" in "CLIENT_ID CreatingThreadId" is the same during the process loading?

Tags: windows, winapi, driver, windows-kernel

I'm trying to write an APC dll injection driver, I've found [this](https://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40737-inject-dll-from-kernel-mode/) example and thought to modify it to my needs.

After I understood the code, this is how I thought to modify it (and my question come from there).

In the [code](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40737-inject-dll-from-kernel-mode/), the writer used [PsLookupThreadByThreadId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-pslookupthreadbythreadid) to receive a referenced pointer to the ETHREAD structure of the targeted process.

```
PsLookupThreadByThreadId(pSpi->Threads[0].ClientId.UniqueThread,&Thread)
```

but to get the [SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750724.aspx) for the [UniqueThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx) handle, he used [ZwQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx)

I want to load my dll right after ntdll is loaded, so I want to use [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutineex) and save the [UniqueThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx) from the [PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_ps_create_notify_info) I got when the callback is called for the process I'm targeting.

And after ntdll is loaded, which I'll know thanks to [PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutineEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetloadimagenotifyroutineex) I could inject my dll using his APC injection logic.

my goal is to inject my dll in the [PloadImageNotifyRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pload_image_notify_routine) callback, but don't use [ZwQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx) as he does to get the [UniqueThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx), but save it in the [PcreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pcreate_process_notify_routine_ex) callback.

So, my question is: Can I trust the [UniqueThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750647.aspx) I get from [PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_ps_create_notify_info) is the same during all the process loading time?

Comment: i can advice you - for begin create driver where callbacks from `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` and `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine` simply do `DbgPrint` of process/thread id passed as parameters and **mandatory** current process/tread id. and view in log for understand - in which context callback called, which id. also for test - create section with `SEC_IMAGE` and call `ZwMapViewOfSection` for map section in current (self) and **another** process. look for output from notify image callback. you need understand context - where this is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` and save the
>   `UniqueThread` from the `PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO` I got when the
>   callback is called for the process I'm targeting.

about `CreatingThreadId` from `PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO`

> The process ID and thread ID of the process and thread that
>   **created** the new process

this id not for new created process/thread, but for creator. if you want inject self dll in the `PloadImageNotifyRoutine` callback - the `PcreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` is useless for you.

the `PloadImageNotifyRoutine` called when image is mapped to target process - inside [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) . you need check that `ProcessId` (*second parameter of `PcreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` - The process ID of the process where image is loaded*) is equal to [`PsGetCurrentProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-psgetcurrentprocessid). this mean that image loaded to the current process and you can use [`KeGetCurrentThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-kegetcurrentthread) - you **not need** `PsLookupThreadByThreadId` at all

> I want to load my dll right after ntdll is loaded

at this moment any user mode structures in process yet not initialized. because it initialized by ntdll. as result - if you inject your apc and force execute it at this moment - you got crash of process. nothing more

i can advice you inject your dll when *kernel32.dll* is loaded. and here you need check that this is load as dll, not simply image mapping - check `ArbitraryUserPointer` in thread teb - are it point to `L"*\\kernel32.dll"`: *smss.exe* map *kernel32.dll* during create `\\KnownDlls` (`ArbitraryUserPointer == 0` in this case), wow64 process several time map *kernel32.dll* (32 and 64 bit) with `L"WOW64_IMAGE_SECTION"` or `L"NOT_AN_IMAGE"` names in `ArbitraryUserPointer`

Comment: Frist of all, Thanks for the correction and explanation about waiting to kernel32.dll to load and not ntdll.dll. Second, I need to understand few things you've written. 1) The thread creating the process is not the thread that loads the modules in that process? 2) The thread that calling the PloadImageNotifyRoutine is the same thread that loads the process? (which is not the thread creating the process)

Comment: @OrielCochavi 1) - of course not. 2) i not understand what you mean under *loads the process*. how i say `PloadImageNotifyRoutine` is called when thread call `ZwMapViewOfSection` and this section created with `SEC_IMAGE` attribute.

Comment: You've written that I can call PsGetCurrentProcessId() and KeGetCurrentThread() from PloadImageNotifyRoutine callback. So my question about it: Is the same thread that loaded the module and caused the invocation of PloadImageNotifyRoutine callback is the same thread that runs the PloadImageNotifyRoutine? (one other thing about 1) is the CreatingThreadId from PS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO is the Tid of (for example) the thread called CreateProcess?

Comment: @OrielCochavi 1) yes - `CreatingThreadId` of **caller** - this is written in msdn. your not need this at all. begin of you question i not understand. again thread which call `ZwMapViewOfSection` if section have `SEC_IMAGE` called (caused the invocation of) PloadImageNotifyRoutine  callback

Comment: Sorry, I misread the documentation of CreatingThreadId. and about 2, I understand that the answer is Yes - thread which call ZwMapViewOfSection is the thread that calls PloadImageNotifyRoutine callback, so I can call PsGetCurrentProcessId() and KeGetCurrentThread() from PloadImageNotifyRoutine callback and get the Pid and Tid of the targeted process.

Comment: `KeGetCurrentThread` return thread object pointer - **not** tid. you **not need** call `PsLookupThreadByThreadId` at all. `PsGetCurrentProcessId` - you need compare with `ProcessId` (where image is mapped) - are image mapped in current process ? also you need check `ArbitraryUserPointer` in thread teb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170905/discussion-between-oriel-cochavi-and-rbmm).