# Windows Kernel Driver: ZwAllocateVirtualMemory causing thread to terminate

Tags: c, windows, driver, low-level, windows-kernel

I'm trying to write an APC dll injection driver, I've found [this](https://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40737-inject-dll-from-kernel-mode/) example and thought to modify it to my needs.

I use [PcreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pcreate_process_notify_routine_ex) to obtain the ProcessId for specific applications I targeting, in this case, "iexplore.exe" and then use [PloadImageNotifyRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nc-ntddk-pload_image_notify_routine) to check if ntdll.dll is already loaded and initialized (from [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50304959/4917303)), and if ntdll.dll is loaded, I call "my" InjectDLL function.

This is the PloadImageNotifyRoutine function that is calling InjectDll:

```
VOID PloadImageNotifyRoutine(
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING FullImageName,
    _In_ HANDLE ProcessId,
    _In_ PIMAGE_INFO ImageInfo
)
{
    PEPROCESS Process = NULL;
    PETHREAD Thread = NULL;
    PCHAR pTeb = nullptr;
    DWORD ArbitraryUserPointer = 0;
    PCHAR pszProcessNameA = nullptr;

    pTeb = (PCHAR)__readfsdword(0x18);
    ArbitraryUserPointer = *(DWORD*)(pTeb + 0x014);

    // If ArbitraryUserPointer points to kernel32.dll it means ntdll.dll is done loading.
    if (FALSE == IsStringEndWith((wchar_t*)ArbitraryUserPointer, L"\\kernel32.dll"))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessId, &Process)))
    {
        return;
    }

    pszProcessNameA = (PCHAR)PsGetProcessImageFileName(Process);
    if (FALSE == StringNCompare(pszProcessNameA, "iexplore.exe", GetStringLength("iexplore.exe")))
    {
        return;
    }

    Thread = KeGetCurrentThread();
    InjectDll(MODULE_PATH, Process, Thread);
    ObDereferenceObject(Process);
}
```

And this is the InjectDll function:

```
BOOLEAN InjectDll(PWCHAR pModulePath, PEPROCESS Process, PETHREAD Thread)
{
    PKINJECT mem;
    ULONG size;

    mem = NULL;
    size = 4096;

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(ZwAllocateVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), (PVOID*)&mem, 0, &size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //more code ...
}
```

I removed here some checks so it would be more clear.

I tried to debug it a little, but it seems like [ZwAllocateVirtualMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory) is trying to allocate memory, failing at some point and terminate the thread.

After it calls ExAllocatePoolWithTag it starting to free memory, unmapping sections and terminate the thread (<= calls I saw at the stack while debugging - didn't really trace each call, but looked at it in general view).

The stack before the thread get terminated:

```
nt!ExAllocatePoolWithTag+0x195
nt!NtAllocateVirtualMemory+0x1066
nt!KiSystemServicePostCall
nt!ZwAllocateVirtualMemory+0x11
kernel_apc_dll_injector!InjectDll+0x54
kernel_apc_dll_injector!PloadImageNotifyRoutine+0x2b0
nt!PsCallImageNotifyRoutines+0x62
```

The process is still visible from task manager, but its Memory is 92k and has no CPU usage, probably because it didn't "cleaned up" properly.

I don't know if my analysis is right, and maybe it even unnecessary for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at first side note - not call `PsLookupProcessByProcessId` from image notify routine. this is simply not need. check that `ProcessId == PsGetCurrentProcessId()`. and if yes - use current process pointer (as you and use in call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` - `NtCurrentProcess()`) otherwise just exist.

now about main - "ZwAllocateVirtualMemory causing thread to terminate" - of course no. thread **not terminate**. it **hung**. at first if thread is terminate - because this is single thread in process at this stage - all process is terminate. but you yourself say that *The process is still visible from task manager*. also how you view call stack of terminated thread ? this also say that thread not terminated but wait inside `ExAllocatePoolWithTag`

problem that callback is execute in some critical region and *The actions that you can perform in this routine are restricted* (The operating system calls the driver's process-notify routine at PASSIVE_LEVEL inside a critical region with normal kernel APCs disabled). one of the restrictions - is call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` - it hung in callback, which you and can see.

so you can not call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` and do injection direct from callback. but solution exist. insert normal kernel apc to current thread. it will be not executed in-place because - normal kernel APCs disabled in callback. but just after you exit from callback and apc will be enabled - your apc executed. and here (in normal routine) you already can call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` and do dll injection

Comment: Thanks. I suspected the thread is only hung in ExAllocatePoolWithTag but I wasn't sure and the fact I saw TerminateThread call made me think the thread gets terminated. Again, Thanks for the advice and the answer.

Comment: @OrielCochavi - insert normal kernel mode apc in callback. and inside it normal routine - allocate memory and do inject (you can even reinitialize and reuse apc object here - for insert user mode apc for inject). do main task not from callback (which is in critical region) but outside. and you view that here allocate memory work ok.